# how can i add drop down list selected values to database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

hello i am new to PHP and ajax. upon choosing the drop down list separate div function will appear and i have to insert both the values . i mean selected option and also the input data in separate div .sorry my english is not good. please help me friends .
thank you in advance

```
<p><label>Affiliate Type</label></p>
<p><select class="inp authInput" id="id_affiliate_type" name="affiliate_type">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;">Select</option>
<option value="I">Individual</option>
<option value="O">Organisation</option>
<div id="errorselect"></div>
</select></p>
<b button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return sendaccountData();" id="updateaccount" name="updateaccount">Update Account Information</b></button>
```

how to store this in phpmyadmin database using ajax and php..

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a javascript listener to react when an option is selected. Then in this listener, you need to send an ajax request to your server with the selected option value as a post/get variable. On your server you need to implement the corresponding php file to handle the ajax request. This php file must get the post/get variable (the selected option value) and insert it in your SQL database. This is the general idea.

Assuming you are using jQuery, the listener must be in a javascript file in your webpage and should look like :

```
// react when the select list changes
$('#id_affiliate_type').on('change', function(e) {

    // get the selected option value
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text(); // or val(), need to confirm this...

    // send the ajax request to your server
    $.ajax({

        // url of your php script which insert data into database
        url: 'your_php_file.php',

        type: 'get' // or 'post' if you prefer

        // variables passed to the script
        data: {selected : selected},

        // callback, request is successful
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('success ' + result);
            // do whatever you need to do after the call
        }

        // callback, something wrong happened
        error: function(result) {
             console.log('error ' + result);
             // do whatever you need to do after the call
        }

        // process completed (success or error)
        complete: function(result) {
        }
    }
}
```

In your PHP file (your_php_file.php) you can access the 'selected' variable by calling :

```
$selected = $_GET['selected'] // (or $_POST)
```

...and then use it to modify your database as needed.

Again this is the general idea, code above is just the general design, not to be used 'as is' but as an inspiration.

You can find lots of examples on SO and elsewhere about implementing a on('change') listener on a select list, sending an ajax request to your server with variables and update a database in PHP from these variables.

Good luck

Comment: sir i have two option in it like "organisation" and "individual", onclicking  the organisation "company " will appear and inputing the data in company input box i have to update to it in database. i have done event call as u mentioned above in code . i have done validation so that user should not continue without selecting the option . but the thing is when i selected INDIVIDUAL option and on clicking the update function it is not allowing me to update it in phpmyadmin

Comment: We need to see more code (server and client side) and more precise error messages to help you.

Comment: `  $(document).on('ready', function() {       $("#id_affiliate_type").change(function () {       var selected_option = $('#id_affiliate_type').val();
if (selected_option === 'O') {$('#id_affiliate_type2').attr('pk','I').show();
}if (selected_option != 'O') {$("#id_affiliate_type2").attr('pk','O').show();
}}) $('#id_affiliate_type').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == 'O')
          //.....................^.......
          {
         $("#detailcompany").show();
          }
          else
          {
         $("#detailcompany").hide();
          }
        }); `

Answer (score 1):

**file1.php**

```
<html>
<select class="opt">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
<div id="msg">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".opt").change(function(){
    var data1 = $(".opt").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        cache:false,
        url:"file2.php",
        data : { foo:data1},    // multiple data sent using ajax
        success: function (html) {

          $('#msg').html(html);
        }
      });
});
</script>
</html>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
$data=$_GET['foo'];
if($data=="option1")
{
    echo "selected value is option1";    // add sql operation here if option 1
}
else if($data=="option2")
{
    echo "selected value is option2";  // add sql operation here if option2
}
?>
```

you can display the data according to the drop down selection in file2.php,

Comment: sir also i am making web chat box customer support for ecommerce can you suggest me idea..?

Comment: you can make a try your self , if any error correction needed i can help you

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. you can make an ajax call and get the value when call is successful and insert that to that DIV.

You will require 1 php file, just for checking the database and giving output, for example: select_org_type.php

**Example : select_org_type.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['affiliate_type'])){
    //use mysqli commands to connect to database and fetch result and store in $result.
    header();//This is very important, it will set your output as pure JSON object and javascript will find it easy to integrate
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Now, here in your page, for example you are using jQuery (which I suggest would be easy to implement ajax call)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var affiliate_type = $('#id_affiliate_type').val();
    $('#updateaccount').on('click',function(){
        $.get('select_org_type.php',{affiliate_type:affiliate_type},function(data){
            $('#errorselect').text(data['column-name']);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is how I make ajax call to populate any select option or give result to any div.

Comment: hello sir , is it possible without json..? in whole code i have used ajax and php ..as you said i have created separate php file there i have written code to connect mysql and insert query to insert data of other filds,

Comment: Yes, Ashish it is also possible without json, you can directly insert html code in any DIV (Dom Element). Your output should be in html and don't put header as application/json.